# Osascript not executing - returns empty array

Tags: php, applescript, osascript

I have an exec() command on my code which runs an applescript from the desktop

```
$cmd = "osascript /Users/***/Desktop/script.app";
exec($cmd, $output);
print_r($output);
```

On one computer it runs without errors, on the second computer it returns an empty array. They are exactly at the same directory, except the username which I change it to the correct one. I also checked the file permissions.

I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this one.

Comment: @MarkSetchell for some reason one machine cannot load the applescript from the file. If I write the script inside my code it works perfectly. Your answer was helpful though

Answer (score 1):

The `PATH` that scripts get exec'ed with may be different on the two machines.

The executable `osascript` lives at:

```
/usr/bin/osascript
```

I guess the machine that works includes `/usr/bin` in the `PATH`, and the one that doesn't work doesn't include it.

**TL;DR**

Give the full path:

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/osascript /Users/***/Desktop/script.app";
exec($cmd, $output);
```